# Node async.js multiple function with waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am not an expert in node and async.js. So expecting help from node js community. So here is my scenario, I want to do 3 operation one after one, each depends on previous result. By using previous result i  need to call async function to retrieve another result. So I decided to go with async waterfall. (Hope I chose correct one).

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    request({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
            url    : url
        },function(error, response, body){
              if(error) {
                  callback(error);
              } else {
                   var result= JSON.parse(body);
                   callback(null,result); //sending to next function
              }
        });
  },
  function(result, callback) {
    //here i want to use the result array in loop async.eachSeries or forEachSeries and fetch another result array using request module then send it to next function
    /*Here I don't know How to process the result*/
    callback(null,result1)
  },
  function(result1, callback) {
    //here i want to use the result1 array and fetch another result array then send it to next function
    callback(null,result2)
  }
], function(error, res) {
  console.log(res); // process final result 
});
```

I referred some tutorials. I couldn't understand that's why end up here in SO. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to help you but I really can't understand what's your question

Comment: Hi, I succeed in first step, (sending result to second function).I really don't know how to process in second step using loops and callback

Comment: I' responding now, please try to edit your own question being more explicit about your question

Answer (score 2):

You *just* gotta use each cb passed in on every function in the waterfall function series.

Btw I feel forced to say:

1. **Don't nest async functions**
2. **Try to use promises instead**
3. **Always check around for whole async module functions, many times, some stuff can be run in parallel**

Ok, so for `waterfall` function, basically requires the following syntax, semantically:

```
async.waterfall(arrayOfFunctions, [optionalResolveCallbackFunction]);
```

the first element in array of function has the following syntax:

```
function (cb) {...};
```

the following n functions will require following syntax:

```
function (param1, param2, ... paramN, cb){...}
```

So, last parameter will be the one used to go to next function or return an error. The number of *waterfall params* is optional.

Each `cb` function follows the *error callback* convention, where error is first parameter to be passed. If an error is returned at any function along the array, the execution will be interrupted and code will go to last `optionalResolveCallbackFunction`.

So, again, even that will produce complicated code (or even risk of performance issues prone) when you decide you've got termination of your loop async.eachSeries or forEachSeries, you will use the `callback` object which happens to be the callback param from the waterfall function to either pass to following function or end the execution.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how it works:

```js
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        request({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: url
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                callback(error);
            } else {
                var result = JSON.parse(body);
                callback(null, result); //sending to next function
            }
        });
    },
    function(result, callback) {
        //here i want to use the result array in loop async.eachSeries or forEachSeries and fetch another result array using request module then send it to next function
        async.each(result, function(item, callback) {
            request({
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                url: url
            }, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    var result = JSON.parse(body);
                    callback(null, result);
                }
            });
        }, function(err, result1) {
            if (!err) {
                callback(null, result1);
            } else {
                callback(err);
            }
        });
    },
    function(result1, callback) {
        request({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: url
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                callback(error);
            } else {
                var result2 = JSON.parse(body);
                callback(null, result2);
            }
        });
    }
], function(error, res) {
    console.log(res); // process final result 
});
```

Comment: I think this is the solution i wanted. I will check this solution. Thanks for your time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi i'm i tried print result1, got `undefined`  console.log(result1)`

Comment: used `asyncmapSeries` instead `async.each`. it's worked

Answer (score 1):

When the function call fail, you should return to make sure you don't get to the next step:

```
function(callback) {
    request({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
            url    : url
        },function(error, response, body){
              if(error) {
                  return callback(error);
              } else {
                   var result= JSON.parse(body);
                   callback(null,result); //sending to next function
              }
        });
  },
```

The result param in the second function is the array you returned from the first call.

```
function(result, callback) {
    //here i want to use the result array in loop async.eachSeries or forEachSeries and fetch another result array using request module then send it to next function
    /*Here I don't know How to process the result*/
    for (var i in result) {
    ...
    }
    callback(null,result1)
  },
```

and then the same for the next function in the series